# Is there a problem with sticking huge amounts of files in a single S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bucket

I have a huge amount (700,000+) of files (about 50kb on avg) I am going to store on S3. I am not sure if I should stick them all in one bucket (which is fine as far as I am concerned), or split them into smaller buckets.

I am only worried that it may take longer for S3 to serve the files if they are all in one bucket, something like if you stick too many things in a Unix directory. Is this a worry, should I break them into more buckets, or just do the most straightforward thing and stick them in 1 bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't stored that many objects myself, but large numbers of objects (even in a single bucket) is exactly the sort of task that S3 was designed to handle. Retrieving a complete list of the objects in that buckets will obviously be a fairly large task, but it shouldn't impair S3's ability to look up keys and return the objects you've put there.

You should be advised that some tools (e.g. graphical tools for "browsing" S3, or some tools that do things like delete the bucket after removing each object) do not handle this well even though S3 is OK. It's just something to be aware of.